# Fragment.onstart is being called before Activity.onstart

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-lifecycle

```
MMuzammil: MainActivity:in onCreate
MMuzammil: FirstFragment:in onAttach
MMuzammil: FirstFragment:in onCreate
MMuzammil: FirstFragment:in onCreateView
MMuzammil: FirstFragment:in onActivityCreated
MMuzammil: FirstFragment:in onStart <----
MMuzammil: MainActivity:in onStart <----
MMuzammil: MainActivity:in onResume
MMuzammil: FirstFragment:in onResume
```

As we can see my Fragment.onStart is being called before Activity.onStart. Any one knows what can be the cause of this behaviour? Because when Activity is moving to the foreground, Activity's callback methods should always call first

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = "MMuzammil";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity:in onCreate");
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FirstFragment()).commit();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity:in onStart");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity:in onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity:in onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity:in onStop");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity:in onDestroy");
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity:in onRestart");
}
}
```

Comment: show more code. The code where you print logs

Comment: @VladMatvienko Please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just because, you are calling super.onStart() and then printing logs in your activity. So basically the onStart() of your activity is running first.

I guess :)

Comment: I'm calling super.onResume() in Activity too. Why the onResume() log of my activity is running first then?

Comment: Some time logs are not in the same manner. And it also differs because the system(Phone OS) might do more heavy job in between onResume of Activity and onResume of Fragment. It will differ from phone to phone, os to os, but the order will remain same their is no doubt in that.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal behavior. If you need to do something in fragment before starting, better override and use onAttach(Context context) method.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Why this isn't the case for onCreate which is called before onStart or for onResume which is called after onStart?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I add this to my `Fragment.onStart()`:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    launch {
        requireActivity().lifecycle.withStarted {
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```